# Tracking uploading files to Internet

Tags: c#, network-traffic

The main question is: could c# application track moment when user starts to upload file from his local machine to internet? It might be any process on machine. Tracking application does not triggered uploading file process.

There is example of code that captures so much outgoing TCP and UDP traffic. But I need to filter only packets contain  file transferring  data.

```
public static void Start()
{
    //get ip address
    IPAddress[] addrList = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;
    string IP = addrList[0].ToString();


    //var devices = SharpPcap.WinPcap.WinPcapDeviceList.Instance;
    var devices = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;

    // differentiate based upon types

    int count = devices.Count;
    if (count < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No device found on this machine");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {               
           // CaptureFlowReceive(IP,  i);
            CaptureFlowSend(IP,i);                
    }
    while (true)
    {               
        //Call refresh function every 1s 
        RefershInfo();
    }

}

private static void CaptureFlowSend(string IP, int deviceID)
{
    ICaptureDevice device = CaptureDeviceList.New()[deviceID];

    device.OnPacketArrival += new PacketArrivalEventHandler(device_OnPacketArrivalSend);
    int readTimeoutMilliseconds = 1000;
    device.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
    string filter = "src host " + IP + " and ip ";
    device.Filter = filter;
    device.StartCapture();

}

private static void device_OnPacketArrivalSend(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
{      

    var rawCapture = e.Packet;
    var packet = Packet.ParsePacket(rawCapture.LinkLayerType, rawCapture.Data);

    var data = packet.PayloadPacket.PayloadPacket.PayloadData;

}

public static void RefershInfo()
{           
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

}
```

Comment: How would you, in a packet, know it is data from a file and not just data created in memory? There is nothing about the content of a file that is – in general – distinguishes from data is memory.

Comment: it was just assumption. The main question is tracking process of starting uploading file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have found solution.
With `netstat -a -n -o` command we could receive all processes that uses tcp and udp sockets. Also we could get DiskUsage info by process from process list received  in previous step. Certainly it is not perfect solution but it is almost closely that I need.